# Invalid cast from Datetime to Decimal

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, xampp

I am trying to sum a column of Times for total hours as shown below:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then

        Dim IntTotalHours As Decimal = 0
        Dim IntPricePerhour As Integer = 0

        For Index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            IntTotalHours += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(Index).Cells(2).Value)

        Next
        TextBox1.Text = IntTotalHours
        TextBox3.Text = FormatCurrency(IntTotalHours * 15)

    End If
End Sub
```

But I get an error on the line:

```
IntTotalHours += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(Index).Cells(2).Value)
```

How do I convert Time to decimal using datagridview?

Comment: Start by turning on Option Strict.  Then, whats in `Cells(2)` - what datatype? and which line has the error.

Comment: Cells(2) is shown in Time, and the line IntTotalHours += has the error.

Comment: Apparently you have a DateTime stored there - a point in time.  You cant accumulate those (Sunday + Tuesday is nonsense, as is 11AM + 6PM).  If you are tracking some sort of time elapsed, it should be a TimeSpan type.  Then use another TimeSpan type to add the total (not an integer unless you want just hours not fractions).